# Convert Tensorflow conv2d_transpose to Caffe Deconvolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, caffe

I've been trying to convert a tensorflow model to caffe which contains `conv2d_transpose` layers to upscale an image. For the TF layer, I constructed the kernel shape as (3, 3, X, X) where X is some number of channels from the previous layer (didn't change channels with deconv) and specified parameters `pad='same', stride=[1,2,2,1], output_shape=(N, 2 * input_shape[1], 2 * input_shape[2], X)` where input_shape was the NHWC format output a previous conv layer.

The conversion I attempted followed from the patttern I've seen/used successfully for converting a caffe `Convolution` layer before:

```
layer = caffe.layers.Deconvolution(prev_layer, name=node.name,
    convolution_param=dict(num_output=X, kernel_size=var.shape[0],
    stride=2, pad=0))

... construct net ...

net.params[layer][0].data[:] = tf_weights.transpose((3,2,0,1))
net.params[layer][1].data[:] = tf_biases
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the output is not the correct size. As is, the code and network produce an output that is too large by 3 pixels in each dimension (I have two conv2d_transpose/Deconvolution layers). By changing `pad=0` to `1` the output becomes similarly too small by 3. Otherwise the output looks more or less like it does in tensorflow, but the boundaries appear messed up which I assume results from this padding issue.

I'm not sure if this conversion is even possible as I've read that deconvolution does not necessarily describe the same operation as a transposed convolution. Let a dude know if it's possible/where this goes wrong. Thanks.

P.S. TF 1.5, and freshly installed caffe (as of commit `87e151281d`)

Comment: As an aside, when I set pad=1, the output looks good without boundary issues. The output is still smaller than expected by 3 pixels in height and width.